# Authorize special caracters in data extension from a cloud page formular response

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, html, cloudpage

I created a cloud page, a landing page with a smart capture and a data extension so as to collect all the answers from the formular.

I saw that i had some response with special caracters.

Does someone know what should i have to add to my html code so as to display "Solène" instead of this :
[image]

```
<div class="srf-field_wrapper">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname*</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="Firstname" required="" type="text" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please give an answer')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
            </div>
```

Comment: I think you might need to set the accept-charset property to UTF-8 on your form as it appears to be defaulting to something else that does not recognize those chars (usually ASCII). (https://www.dofactory.com/html/form/accept-charset)